# How to stop Mathematica from using polynomial relations to simplify expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials

I am making a table whose entries involve Jacobi polynomials, $P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}(x)$. Each entry contains some expression polynomials as a function of $n$, i.e. the first entry will be some function of Jacobi polynomials with $n$ evaluated at zero, the next will have $n=1$ etc.

I need the first entry to be n=0. However this causes issues because Mathematica automatically replaces any derivatives of the Jacobi polynomials with a Jacobi polynomial $n-1$, according to eq. (14) here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiPolynomial.html .

When I evaluate my functions, the elements for $n=0$ end up including Jacobi polynomials of the form `JacobiP[-1,alpha,beta,x]`, which Mathematica cannot handle.

Is there any way to stop Mathematica from simplifying the derivatives of the polynomials, so that when I specify the value of $n$ I can evaluate the correct expression?

Comment: You could e.g. use: HoldForm@D[JacobiP[n, alpha, beta, x], x]

Comment: Why do not you directly write 0 for the corresponding entry? In general, our help would be much better if you give your code along with an example of the form in which you want to obtain your table.

Comment: Didi you try `FullSimplify[D[JacobiP[n, alpha, beta, x], x] /. n -> 0]`?

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks, that's what I wanted.